# Prevent optional dependencies to be installed on Heroku

Tags: heroku, cypress, package.json

part of my `package.json`:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
  "cypress": "^8.2.0",
  "cypress-commands": "^1.1.0",
  "cypress-expect": "^2.4.1",
  "cypress-file-upload": "^4.1.1"
},
```

I know that `npm install --no-optional` prevents optinal dependencies to be installed locally. But no idea how to pass that flag on Heroku

Comment: can you try using `npm ci --no-optional` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_OMIT=optional
```

And this is exactly what it's needed for.  We don't want heroku spending time and resource loading and building test packages.